# Deserializing JSON TweetSharp TwitterStatus

Tags: json, serialization, json.net, tweetsharp

I'm using Daniel Crenna's TweetSharp http://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp

To serialise a TwitterStatus to file I use the code

```
sw.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(twitterStatus));
```

which produces the text

`{"Id":288653019971727360,"InReplyToUserId":null,"InReplyToStatusId":null,"InReplyToScreenName":null,"truncated":false,"favorited":false,"Text":"Found the bug, dear old regular expressions","Source":"web","User":{"Id":1148081,"FollowersCount":793,"Name":"Tim Regan","Description": [...]`

(N.B. I won't include it all, unless that'll help diagnosis?)

My line of code to deserialize the TwitterStatus is

```
var tweet = (TwitterStatus)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(line);
```

But that gives the error

`System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'TweetSharp.TwitterStatus'.
  Source=TweetColorMVVM
  StackTrace:
       at TweetColorMVVM.Model.Tweets.LoadSavedTweets(String screenName) in c:\TFSCML\Users\Tim\MSR.Makefest\TwitterColor\TweetColorMVVM\Model\Tweets.cs:line 132
       at TweetColorMVVM.Model.Tweets.LoadTweets(Object state) in c:\TFSCML\Users\Tim\MSR.Makefest\TwitterColor\TweetColorMVVM\Model\Tweets.cs:line 78
       at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
       at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
       at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()`

Can anyone see what I've got wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have written:

```
var tweet = (TwitterStatus)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(line, typeof(TwitterStatus));
```

It works now.